# How does a C++ I/O stream mask the underlying computer system's I/O volatility?

Tags: io, volatility

The question is in the title. I did surf the web for some answers to this, but nothing really answered it. I got definitions for I/O stream and definitions for volatility, but never any links between the two. Thanks in advance!